# Add NSUserDefaults for specific Username

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to add data in the `NSUserDefaults` object for specific Username but I'm a little bit embarrassed I don't know how can I do it? 
I started this way:

```
//Set data
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 defaults.set(invnr, forKey: "Person")
 defaults.synchronize()

//getData
  let name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Person")
  print(name)
```

This way works, but for all users, I want to add data in session for specific username. Hope you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
let username = "Blahblahblah"
```

So, let's try it in this way:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(invnr, forKey: "Person \(username)")
defaults.synchronize()

//getData
let name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Person \(username)")
print(name)
```

Comment: `synchronize()` is irrelevant.